# Deleting DataFrame rows following first NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem which I am only able to find a solution for the reverse problem. I need to be able to delete all the rows in the DataFrame following the first NaN value in a specific column. I cannot find a function similar to the pandas function `first_valid_index` but in reverse.

What I have is something similar to;

```
data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'NaN', 'Nevada'],
        'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
        'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and what I want to see at the end is this;

```
data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio'],
        'year': [2000, 2001, 2002],
        'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So after the first NaN found in the `state` column, the DataFrame gets sliced to only include above it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'NaN' represents real `NaN` in your sample data set:

```
In [341]: new = frame.loc[:frame.state.isnull().idxmax()-1]

In [342]: new
Out[342]:
   pop state  year
0  1.5  Ohio  2000
1  1.7  Ohio  2001
2  3.6  Ohio  2002
```

**Explanation**: `idxmax()` - returns an index of the **first** maximum value.

Demo:

```
In [345]: frame.loc[1,'state'] = np.nan

In [346]: frame
Out[346]:
   pop   state  year
0  1.5    Ohio  2000
1  1.7     NaN  2001
2  3.6    Ohio  2002
3  2.4     NaN  2001
4  2.9  Nevada  2002

In [347]: frame.loc[:frame.state.isnull().idxmax()-1]
Out[347]:
   pop state  year
0  1.5  Ohio  2000

In [348]: frame.state.isnull().idxmax()
Out[348]: 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `idxmin`?

Comment: Apparently, `NaN` here is string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, no, `idxmin()` - will return an index of __first__ not null value

Comment: @MaxU: but the question says the *first NaN* (title).

Comment: @JohnGalt, yes, i've intentionally converted it to `np.nan`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, please see an "explanation" part

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, why  did you delete your answer?

Comment: @MaxU If there are no NaN values, `idxmax` will return the first index of the maximum, which is zero in this case because the maximum value is False (i.e. 0) which first occurs at index 0.  See my answer for work around.

Comment: @Alexander, that's true. But it's fairly easy to work around it, isn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution below will work if the `NaN` is the first element in the Series or if there are no `NaN` values in the series.

For `NaN`, I have allowed null values or any string that starts with `NaN`.

It finds the index location of the first `NaN` value (or None if there are no `NaN` values) and then indexes the dataframe.

```
idx = (frame['state'].isnull() | frame['state'].str.startswith('NaN'))
idx = idx.idxmax() if idx.any() else None
frame[:idx]
```

Comment: ++ for the workaround of the case when there are no NaN's